# What does 字以外に mean?

Tags: translation, words

I don't usually ask questions like this, but I'm having a hard time figuring this out:

> 字以外に日本の好きなのありますか？

The "ji igai ni" is throwing me off, is it asking whether you like other things about Japan? Or what else you like about Japan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without further context, it would appear to mean "is there anything about Japan that you like, other than the characters 日本?"